# Resolving "DNS name does not exist" activating Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I am trying to activate a new copy of Windows 8 Pro. When clicking on the Activate button in the Windows Activation screen comes back with:

> DNS name does not exist

[image: Windows 8 Activation Error]

How can I go ahead an activate Windows 8?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Microosoft Knowledge Base 929826 article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929826) suggests it's looking for a KMS host server.

Make sure you're on (or VPNed into) your work or school campus when activating. If that doesn't apply to you there's a method listed on that article that shows how to use your MAK instead:

1. Run the command prompt as an administrator
2. Enter `slmgr -ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx` where `xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx` is your product key.

Then try activating again.

Comment: Prefect! It was the case since they only offer VL downloads for Pro at the moment.

Comment: Thanks...this worked on Windows 10 Enterprise as well. Weirdly, the "Change product key" button in GUI created an invisible modal, and this was the only way I could get the new key in.